# How to add a GET variable to the current URL?

Tags: php, variables, search, get

I have a question, i want to make some search page, and it needs a get variable to sort the results. So if someone enters the page without that GET variable, reload the page and make it appear, for example you enter www.myweb.com/search and automatically reloads  and changes to www.myweb.com/search/?sort=ascending (because that variable is necessary) .

I hope you understand me, good bye

Comment: Can't you use a default if $_GET['sort'] isn't sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for what you're looking to do:

```
if (empty($_GET['sort'])) {
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?sort=ascending');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: If a user already has get parameters in the url it will override them.

Comment: No problem, i know how to do the rest. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From within the file executed when `www.myweb.com/search` is requested, you should have a default setting when $_GET['sort'] isn't available. For this Answer, I'll be using PHP for my examples since you didn't specify.

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['sort'])) {
    $sort = 'ascending';
}
// the rest of your code
```

Alternatively, you *could* force a redirect, but the previous example is more elegant.

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['sort'])) {
    header('Location: www.myweb.com/search/?sort=ascending');
    exit;
}
```

Keep in mind, the second solution would throw away anything else, i.e.,  other $_GET's, like `item=widget` or `color=blue`

*Note to others posting `!isset` as an answer. That will not work!* Example:

```
www.myweb.com/search/?sort=&foo=bar
```

`!isset($_GET['sort'])` === false!

`empty($_GET['sort'])` is the proper route to take in this circumstance.

Answer (score -2):

It is better to define the variable by yourself rather then redirecting. Just check with isset if the variable is defined or not. It it has not been defined you can set it yourself as below.

```
if(!isset($_GET['sort']))
{
$_GET['sort']='ascending";
}
```